# how to check if the swipe is in the forward direction of my player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that I am moving my player based on the swipe direction but I want to move my player when the swipe is in the forward direction of my player. To put it simply

```cs
if (swipeDirection == myPlayersForwardDirection)
{
    //then move forward
}
else
{
   //don't move
}
```

I tried many things but didn't know how to compare the swipe direction and players forward direction.

and here is my code for the swipe.

```cs
//inside class
Vector2 firstPressPos;
Vector2 secondPressPos;
Vector2 currentSwipe;
 
public void Swipe()
{
     if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
     {
         //save began touch 2d point
        firstPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y);
     }
     if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
     {
            //save ended touch 2d point
        secondPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y);
       
            //create vector from the two points
        currentSwipe = new Vector2(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);
           
        //normalize the 2d vector
        currentSwipe.Normalize();
 
        //swipe upwards
        if(currentSwipe.y > 0  currentSwipe.x > -0.5f  currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
        {
            Debug.Log("up swipe");
        }
        //swipe down
        if(currentSwipe.y < 0  currentSwipe.x > -0.5f  currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
        {
            Debug.Log("down swipe");
        }
        //swipe left
        if(currentSwipe.x < 0  currentSwipe.y > -0.5f  currentSwipe.y < 0.5f)
        {
            Debug.Log("left swipe");
        }
        //swipe right
        if(currentSwipe.x > 0  currentSwipe.y > -0.5f  currentSwipe.y < 0.5f)
        {
            Debug.Log("right swipe");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two Vectors, the best solution is to use `Vector3.Dot.` You must be familiar with this concept in high school Geometry. Anyway, this is how it works:

- It returns **`1`** if the two vectors are completely in the same direction.
- If two vectors are perpendicular, it returns **`0`**.
- If the two vectors are opposite, it returns **`-1`**.
- The rest of the numbers were placed according to the degree of correspondence between them.

So you can condition a value for example `0.9f` for relative matching.

```cs
if (Vector3.Dot(swipeDirection,myPlayersForwardDirection) > .9f)
{
    //then move forward
}
else
{
    //don't move
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you so much, brother... I have figure out another way, but this method is very good.... so, thanks...

Comment: @SannanCh Thank you, dear.  Anyway, if you think this method can be an alternative, please give a green tick so that the respondent's effort is not wasted.